# Looking for Java EE Version installed with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jee

I am relatively new to Java development. I have a couple of questions:
1. How do I know the version of Eclipse Java EE installation?
2. How do I upgrade to a newer version say Java EE 7.

Regards,
Janet T.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271482/configure-j2ee-version-on-eclipse) may help

Answer (score 0):

Your eclipse config file should indicate which java version eclipse is running on. This is normally specified by the '-vm' tag, as it indicates which directory eclipse is using to look for the java.exe file.

To upgrade to a newer version, you can download it from the Oracle website and then point the '-vm' to the directory where you installed the downloaded version. You can have multiple java versions installed on your machine. The one specified in your JAVA_HOME system properties is the one that is normally used to build your jars if building from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The White Bullet answer is related to Java version, if you're talking about Java EE, the version will depend on your container (JBoss/Wildfly, WebLogic, Glassfish, etc...). Just choose one Java EE container and the version of it will define the Java EE version, for example, Wildfly 10.0.0.Final is intended for Java EE 7

Comment: where to check Java EE version for Wildfly 11.0. I checked release notes @ http://wildfly.org/news/tags/release/page/2/, but no where the version is mentioned, whereas for Wildfly 14 release they have mentioned - it's Java EE8 certified.